# how to select highest to lowest order value with horizontal wise in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is my table marks

| quiz_1_marks | quiz_2_marks | quiz_3_marks | quiz_4_marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86.5 | 90.3 | 69.9 | 43.2 |
| 36.27 | 54.9 | 28.8 | 69.65 |

And I want select marks like this

| max1 | max2 | max3 | max4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90.3 | 86.5 | 69.9 | 43.2 |
| 69.65 | 54.9 | 36.7 | 28.8 |

Comment: Consider revising your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpivot, sort, pivot with conditional aggregation

```
select max1, max2, max3, max4
from tbl_marks
cross join lateral (
   select  
      max(case rn when 1 then qm end) max1,
      max(case rn when 2 then qm end) max2,
      max(case rn when 3 then qm end) max3,
      max(case rn when 4 then qm end) max4
   from (
      select q.m qm, row_number() over(order by q.m desc) rn
      from (
         select quiz_1_marks union all
         select quiz_2_marks union all
         select quiz_3_marks union all
         select quiz_4_marks
      ) q(m)
    ) t
 ) t;
```

See the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e3f41bb087242c97550f9119cc313ec)

Comment: what does mean by rn and qm

Comment: `rn` and `qm` are aliases of the columns computed by the subqueries.

Comment: Thank you it's working but decimal points showing on it how to remove it

Comment: Output format fine tuning is better done at UI level rather then DB server.